# technical inquiry - HTML transfer of image from server to browser

Tags: html, image, server

When an image is uploaded from the client's machine to the client (browser), it requires `FileReader()` API in html, thereafter a `base64 encoded url` (say) of the image is sent in chunks to the server, where it needs to be re-assembled. All of this is taken care by the developer.

However, when an image is sent from the server to the client, only the `directory path of the image` inside the server machine suffices, no chunking and encoding is required.

My questions are: 
1. Does the server send the image in chunks to the html file. If it does not, how does sending full images not bottle server's network? What would happen in case of large video files? 
2. In what form of binary data is the image sent to the client - `base64url / ArrayBuffer / binarystring / text / etc.` 
3. If the server does send the image in chunks, who is doing the chunking and the re-assembly on the client thereafter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML isn't really important here. What you care about are the transport protocols used - HTTP and TCP, most likely.

HTTP isn't chunked by default, though there are advanced headers that do allow that - those are mostly used to support seeking in large files (e.g. PDF, video). Technically, this isn't really chunking - it's just the infrastructure for allowing for partial downloads (i.e. "Give me data from byte 1024 to byte 2048.").

TCP is a stream-based protocol. From programmer point of view, that's all there is to it - no chunking. Technically, though, it will process your input data and send it as distinct packets that are reassembled in-order on the other side. This is a matter of practicality - it allows you to manage data latency, streaming, packet retransmission etc. TCP handles the specifics during connection negotiation - flow control, window sizing, congestion control...

That's not the end of it, though. All the other layers add their own bits - their own ways to package the payload and split it as necessary, their own ways to handle routing and filtering, their own ways to handle congestion...

Finally, just like HTTP natively supports downloads, it supports uploading data as well. Just send an HTTP request (usually POST or PUT) and write data in a format the server understands - anything from text through base-64 to raw binary data. The limiting factor in your case isn't the server, the browser or HTTP - it's JavaScript. The basic mechanism is still the same - a request followed by a response.

Now, to address your questions:

1. Server doesn't send images to the HTML file. HTML only contains an URL of the image[1], and when the browser sees an URL in the `img` tag, it will initiate a new, separate request just for the image data. It isn't fundamentally different from downloading a file from a link. As for the transfer itself, it follows pretty much exactly the same way as the original HTML document - HTTP headers, then the payload.
2. Usually, raw binary data. HTTP is a text-based protocol, but it's payload can be arbitrary. There's little reason to use Base-64 to transfer image data (though in the past, there have been HTTP and FTP servers that didn't support binary at all, so you had to use something like Base-64).
3. The HTTP server doesn't care (with the exception of "partial downloads" mentioned above). The underlying network protocols handle this.

[1] Nowadays, there's methods to embed images directly in the HTML text, but it's of varying practicality depending on the image size, caching requirements etc.